# jQuery switched to 1.11.1 from 1.7.1 and now I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery

I recently switched from jquery 1.11.1 from 1.7.1 and now I am having an issue with some old code:

```
$('#searchtext').autocomplete({source:'search.php'});
```

and if I comment that out, I get an error on this line:

```
$("#top").live('click',function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:200}, 'slow');
    return false;
});
```

I have no document ready or load at the top of this code, but when I did that I ran into the same issue. :( Any suggestions.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for `.live()` - _As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.autotomcomplete()` function comes from jQuery UI library, it's doesnt come from jQuery lib. jQuery UI is a dependency and `autocomplete` is a plugin which you may download seperately but it will still require jQuery UI.

As for `.live()` function, you should rename it to `.on()` (it is the preferred method in the newer versions of jQuery), `.live()` is deprecated.

Comment: Fantastic, fixed everything. Thank you very much